# How to iterate through folders and copy files

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have the following code which copies everything in to the right place except File 1, File 2 & File 3.

**Source**: "C:\dir" 
**Target**: "C:\tmp\Backup"

```
Public Sub CopyDirectory(source As DirectoryInfo, target As DirectoryInfo)

    'Recursively call the DeepCopy Method for each Directory
    For Each MyDir As DirectoryInfo In source.GetDirectories()
        CopyDirectory(MyDir, target.CreateSubdirectory(projectName & "\" & MyDir.Name))
    Next

    ' Go ahead and copy each file in "source" to the "target" directory
    For Each MyFile As FileInfo In source.GetFiles()

        If Not (File.Exists(Path.Combine(target.FullName, MyFile.Name))) Then
            MyFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, MyFile.Name))
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("File already exist")
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

File 1, 2 & 3 should go inside the "Dir" folder, but it keeps showing up in the "Backup" folder.

```
C:\
|_ tmp
    |_ Backup
        |_ Dir
            |_ Folder 1
                |_ File 11
                |_ File 12
                |_ File 13
            |_ Folder 2
                |_ File 21
                |_ File 22
                |_ File 23
            |_ Folder 3
                |_ File 31
                |_ File 32
                |_ File 33

        |_ File 1
        |_ File 2
        |_ File 3
```

How do I make sure that File 1, 2, and 3 gets copied inside the "Dir" folder?

Comment: check that target.CreateSubdirectory(projectName & "\" & MyDir.Name) returns DirInfo for which directory

Comment: What is the variable `projectName`? It is not in the parameter list or defined in your function. Is it a member variable of your class?

Comment: What is path of source file for file1, file2, file3 ?

Comment: If file1, file2, file3 are in directory c:\dir\ then the result is as expected.

Comment: Hi Adarsh, Original files are in C:\Dir\, and they should be copied into C:\tmp\Backup\Dir\ folder. Instead, File 1, 2 & 3 are getting copied into the C:\tmp\Backup folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies in this line:

```
CopyDirectory(MyDir, target.CreateSubdirectory(projectName & "\" & MyDir.Name))
```

I take it you want to create the new folder at target. For that to happen you do this:

```
CopyDirectory(MyDir, target.CreateSubdirectory(MyDir.Name))
```

Ehm right. Missed this line:

Source: "C:\dir" Target: "C:\tmp\Backup"

Your program is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. Take the files in dir and put it in backup. If you want that to change you need to set target to C:\temp\Backup\dir when you start the first recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Code was altered to the below.
Thank you WozzeC.

Final Code:

```
                    fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(txtSLocation1.Text).TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
                projectName = Path.GetFileName(txtSLocation1.Text)

                Dim SourcePath As New IO.DirectoryInfo(txtSLocation1.Text)
                Dim DestPath As New IO.DirectoryInfo(txtDLocation1.Text & "\" & projectName)

                DestString = txtDLocation1.Text & "\" & projectName
                CopyDirectory(SourcePath, DestPath)
```

CopyDirectory

```
Public Sub CopyDirectory(source As DirectoryInfo, target As DirectoryInfo)


    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(DestString)) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(DestString)
    End If

    'Recursively call the DeepCopy Method for each Directory
    For Each MyDir As DirectoryInfo In source.GetDirectories()
        CopyDirectory(MyDir, target.CreateSubdirectory(MyDir.Name))
    Next

    ' Go ahead and copy each file in "source" to the "target" directory
    For Each MyFile As FileInfo In source.GetFiles()

        If Not (File.Exists(Path.Combine(target.FullName, MyFile.Name))) Then
            MyFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, MyFile.Name))
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("File already exist")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```